# Cannot read properties from custom config

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.2.1. I want to put some configuration into another file besides `Config.groovy.`

I put it in a file called `My-config.groovy`. It's contents are short and simple

```
uten {
    currency="USD"
    user="smacko"
}
```

I add the following to the top of my `Config.groovy`

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:My-config.groovy"]
```

In my code when I do:

```
String user = grailsApplication.config.uten["user"]
```

At runtime, I check in the debugger and the `user` variable is just a `String` with the value `groovy.util.ConfigObject`. What are my doing wrong?

Comment: What does grailsApplication.config.uten.user give you?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I have updated the last two lines of question. Thanks.

Comment: in which folder is My-config.groovy located?

Comment: try moving `My-config.groovy` to `src/java`. i dont think it gets automatically added to classpath from `conf`

Answer (score 0):

If you want uten to be a map your the config should look like this:

```
uten = [
    currency: "USD",
    user: "smacko"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am skeptical about using a file name with `-`. Your approach is correct in using the config file. If there is no resistance in changing the file name to `MyConfig.groovy` then this option will work effortlessly:

```
grails.config.locations = [MyConfig]
```

Comment: the default grails Config.groovy has examples of files with `-` (albeit in comments), so I presume it should be valid